# How can I change a button´s text by clicking another button? - Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

So basically this what I tried:

```
@IBAction func buttonTwo(sender: UIButton){  // <- Should UIButton be AnyObject ? 
 buttonOne.setTitle("Do", forState: .Normal) // This wont change the other buttons text 
}
```

// After knowing how to this, my goal is to follow this logic:

```
@IBAction func buttonTwo(sender: UIButton) {
    if ( buttonOne == "What") {
         buttonOne.setTitle("Do", forState: .Normal)
    } else {
         buttonOne.setTitle(¨What", forState: .Normal)
        }  
}
```

Comment: You're if statement is missing brackets, `setTile` is an apparent typo, and you are trying to compare a `UIButton` with a `String` using `===`.

Comment: I know this... I just wanted to state my logic, I typed it fast here. Even with the correct command it will not work like I want... I corrected it.

Comment: Help us help you. Its difficult for us to help you if you're not willing to even run your code through the compiler. I'm sure if you actually tried to run this in Xcode, you'll be able to fix the compiler errors and see whats wrong.

Comment: I did run my code on the compiler, my main problem is changing another buttons text by clicking a different button which is not working with the above code ( buttonOne.setTitle("Do", forState: .Normal) , and I´ve tried looking for solutions for this.

Comment: Did try to make it clear on my post. Sorry for any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
@IBAction func buttonTwo(sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = buttonOne.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal) { //make sure title is not nil
        if ( text == "What") {
            buttonOne.setTitle("Do", forState: .Normal)
        } else {
            buttonOne.setTitle("What", forState: .Normal)
        }  
    }
}
```

I just ran this fine:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!

    @IBAction func changeText(sender: AnyObject) {

        if let text = buttonOne.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal) {
            if ( text == "What") {
                buttonOne.setTitle("Do", forState: .Normal)
            } else {
                buttonOne.setTitle("What", forState: .Normal)
            }  
        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

are you sure the @IBOutlet is connected properly for buttonOne?

NOTE: when creating the @IBAction from the story board it sets sender to AnyObject.  I changed it to see if it worked as UIButton and it does.

an array option like you asked

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!

var buttonArray:[UIButton] = []

@IBAction func changeText(sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = buttonArray[0].titleForState(UIControlState.Normal) {
        if ( text == "What") {
            buttonArray[0].setTitle("Do", forState: .Normal)
        } else {
            buttonArray[0].setTitle("What", forState: .Normal)
        }  
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    buttonArray.append(buttonOne)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: I runned this and it gives me an error saying: `(UIButton) -> 0´ does not have a member named ´titleLabel´).  I am not sure this are the correct commands to use, when I type ´buttonOne.setTitle("Do, forState: .Normal), it doesnt try to auto-complete for setTitle, and it doesnt turn setTitle and .Normal into a different color like it should.

Comment: I modified the if let line.  Try that

Comment: Same thing, but with the titleForState.

Comment: are you sure your button has a title set to begin with?

Comment: Yes, it does have a title.

Comment: I'm confused than because UIButton objects have a titleLabel property      https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/

Comment: I did a quick test and it works fine.  See my updates

Comment: It might be the fact that I was using IBAction for both, and not IBOutlet for buttonOne. But I have to do the same thing I did for buttonTwo to buttonOne, so I will try and see if I can have action and outlet at the same time for the same button. Thanks a lot for your help and for caring.

Comment: you can have an IBAction and an IBOutlet for both buttons without any issue, just don't name them the same.  Just remember to use the IBOutlet when you want to change any of the properties of the button, or any object on your storyboard for that matter.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. But I have to do this to an 'array' of several buttons, and seems like I would have to repeat a lot of code and doesn't seem efficient, also the same button I click I has to change its text also. Do you know of any other way of doing this?

Comment: you could add them to an array of UIButton in your viewDidLoad function.  Se my last edit.  You would just need to keep track of which button is where.

Comment: How can I have all my different buttons in just one Outlet or Action?

Comment: you can have your different buttons all call the same action function.  Then you can determine who called the function based on the sender variable.  You cant however have multiple buttons associated with a single outlet.  That would be like saying the pen you are holding is actually multiple pens, which we all know cant happen.